# java port scanner not working

Tags: java, sockets

I am taking a free online course for cybersecurity here https://cybersecuritybase.github.io/

Par of the course they want you to create a java port scanner they provide some of the code and you add the port scanner portion and i am having issues with it.  Java is not a language i am really familiar with so i feel it's something simple but can't seem to figure it out.

code is here

```
package sec.portscanner;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.TreeSet;
import java.io.IOException;
public class PortScanner {

    final static int MIN_PORT = 1024;
    final static int MAX_PORT = 49151;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Which address should I scan?");
        String address = reader.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Start at port?");
        int start = Integer.parseInt(reader.nextLine());
        System.out.println("End at port?");
        int end = Integer.parseInt(reader.nextLine());

        Set<Integer> ports = getAccessiblePorts(address, start, end);
        System.out.println("");

        if (ports.isEmpty()) {
            System.out.println("None found :(");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Found:");
            ports.stream().forEach(p -> System.out.println("\t" + p));
        }
    }

    public static Set<Integer> getAccessiblePorts(String address, int start, int end) {
        Set<Integer> accessiblePorts = new TreeSet<>();
        start = Math.max(start, MIN_PORT);
        end = Math.min(end, MAX_PORT);

        for (int port = start; port <= end; port++) 
        {
            try {
                Socket socket = new Socket();
                socket.connect(new InetSocketAddress(address, port), 50000);
                socket.close();
            } catch(IOException e) {
                    System.out.println(e);
                    }
            }

        return accessiblePorts;
    }
}
```

The portion I created is the for loop with the socket scan.  It always prints out none found no matter what address i provide and i am not sure how to fix this.  any pointers would be great I have searched and from what i see nothing is stand out wrong( at least i hope)

Comment: im doing that course as well and i dont know s**t about java :) im having an error 'java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect' , which means my server isn't running (after googling it) , did u run into this kind of problem as well?

Comment: What's that 50000 in `socket.connect()`? Don't just say "port", since the port is already in `InetSocketAddress()`. Why isn't this part written like this: `socket.connect(new InetSocketAddress(address, port), port);`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you are not adding to the `accessiblePorts` Set

try

```
Socket socket = new Socket();
socket.connect(new InetSocketAddress(address, port), 50000);
socket.close();
accessiblePorts.add (port);
```

Comment: awesome seems that worked thanks i'll make sure this is something i watch for later.